# OpenWeatherMap JSON API forecast for rain and snow

Tags: json, api, gson, openweathermap

I am facing problems forcing my code run smoothly when there is no value for Parameters rain and snow. Actually it loops as long as there are values for these parameters and if not it ends.

I have included gson library for helping me get the values as JSON objects/strings/double etc.

```
   for (int l=0; l<40; l++) {
        Forecast fcath = new Forecast();
        fcath.setMain_temp(obj_fcath.get("list").getAsJsonArray().get(l).getAsJsonObject().get("main").getAsJsonObject().get("temp").getAsDouble());
        fcath.setWeather_description(obj_fcath.get("list").getAsJsonArray().get(l).getAsJsonObject().get("weather").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("description").getAsString());
        fcath.setClouds_all(obj_fcath.get("list").getAsJsonArray().get(l).getAsJsonObject().get("clouds").getAsJsonObject().get("all").getAsInt());
        fcath.setWind_speed(obj_fcath.get("list").getAsJsonArray().get(l).getAsJsonObject().get("wind").getAsJsonObject().get("speed").getAsDouble());
        fcath.setDt_txt(obj_fcath.get("list").getAsJsonArray().get(l).getAsJsonObject().get("dt_txt").getAsString());
        fcath.setRain(obj_fcath.get("list").getAsJsonArray().get(l).getAsJsonObject().get("rain").getAsJsonObject().get("3h").getAsDouble());
        fcath.setSnow(obj_fcath.get("list").getAsJsonArray().get(l).getAsJsonObject().get("snow").getAsJsonObject().get("3h").getAsDouble());
        f.add(fcath);
        System.out.println("Date: " + f.get(l).getDt_txt() + " Temp: " + f.get(l).getMain_temp() + " Celsius " + " Chance of Rain: " + f.get(l).getRain() + " Chance of Snow: " + f.get(l).getSnow());
    }
```

Without fcath.setRain and fcath.setSnow code lines the output is the following:
[Working output photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqyAG.png)

Assuming that there is no rain chance in the forecast 
e.g.
fcath.setRain(obj_fcath.get("list").getAsJsonArray().get(l).getAsJsonObject().get("rain").getAsJsonObject().get("3h").getAsDouble()); **== {}**
it gives me NullPointerException

[NullPointerException photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTNSq.png)

Comment: Which problems?

Comment: If the value (double) of rain or snow is null then the code fails.

Comment: Yes, but if you expect that somebody helps you, you need to explain what means "code fails". You have some exceptions? Can you put it on the question? What is the output? We are not wizards that can guess what is happening to you, neither we can execute your code.

Comment: Edited with photos of output and better explanation of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is still hard to say with the information provided, but seems that if the is no rain chance, then probably

```
 obj_fcath.get("list").getAsJsonArray().get(l).getAsJsonObject().get("rain").getAsJsonObject()
```

is `null`. Then you cannot do a `get("3h").getAsDouble()` from a null object.

Comment: Found a solution surrounding these code lines with try catch(Exception)! Don't know if the proper solution though.

Comment: In some cases catching an exception can be a good idea. In other case probably you must avoid the cause of the exception. In you case, catching a `NullPointerException` can be a solution. Other solution is checking if the value is null before accessing to the method `get("3h").getAsDouble()`.